# itextsharp change margins no document.SetPageSize

Tags: itext, margins

I added the function below to change the margins for the page
at every page change.
I found the forum a method that sets the size of the page:

```
document.SetPageSize (New Rectangle (36.0F, 36.0F, 52.0F, PageFooter.TotalHeight))
```

But I do not want to change the size of the page, but those margins.
thanks

```
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {

        try 
        { 

        DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();
        foreach (DataSet obj in report.arrayDs)
        {
            dsReport = obj;
            break;
        }
        Single topMargin = 0;
        if (document.PageNumber != 1)
        {
            if (report.repeatHead) //ripete l'intestazione del report su tutte le pagine di stampa
            {
                repeatHead(writer, document);
                topMargin = 60;
            }
            else
            {
                if (document.PageNumber == 2) //ripete l'intestazione del report solo sulla second pagina dopo la copertina
                {
                    repeatHead(writer, document);
                    topMargin = 60;
                }
                else
                {
                    topMargin = Convert.ToSingle(dsReport.Tables["REPORT_STYLE"].Rows[0]["topMargin"]) * 10;
                }
            }
            document.SetMargins(Convert.ToSingle(dsReport.Tables["REPORT_STYLE"].Rows[0]["leftMargin"]) * 10,
                    Convert.ToSingle(dsReport.Tables["REPORT_STYLE"].Rows[0]["rightMargin"]) * 10,
                    topMargin,
                    Convert.ToSingle(dsReport.Tables["REPORT_STYLE"].Rows[0]["bottomMargin"]) * 10);
        }

        }
        catch
        { throw; }

    }
```

Comment: I see that you found the `SetMargins()` method, which is OK, but it is **not allowed** to change the `Document` in a page event. Why are you doing this in a page event?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. Should I change with every change of page, where treat them?
thanks

Comment: You might want to rephrase that question. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, when a large report ends on two pages, the first page put:
Top margin = 60;

On page hits:
Top margin = 0;

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification in the comments, you want the top margin of the first page to be 60 and the top margin of the second page to be 0.

This is shown in the following screen shot:
[image]

The Java code to achieve this looks like this:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    float left = 30;
    float right = 30;
    float top = 60;
    float bottom = 0;
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, left, right, top, bottom);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    document.setMargins(left, right, 0, bottom);
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        document.add(new Paragraph("This is a test"));
    }
    document.close();
}
```

If you want to port this to C#, you need to change some lower cases into upper cases. You already knew most of the methods, for instance: I see `document.SetMargins(...)` in your page event.